# Combine duplicate values

Tags: php, mysql, join, group-by, grouping

I have three tables: `projects`, `proj_categ` and `categories`.

```
projects(id, title)
proj_categ(id, proj_id, categ_id)
categories(id, title)
```

Table `proj_categ` connects two tables (`projects` and `categories`) as shown below. **One project may have one or more categories.**
[image]

**PHP & mysql**

```
$projects = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM projects"); 

while($projrow=mysql_fetch_array($projects))
{
    $projid = $projrow['id'];

    $categories= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories JOIN proj_categ ON categories.id=proj_categ.categ_id where proj_id='".$projid."'"); 

    while($caterow=mysql_fetch_array($categories))
    {
        echo $caterow['title']." ";
        echo $projrow['title']."<br/>";
    }
}
```

**FYI: HTML code**

`$caterow['title']` to be inserted into `<li class="gallery-item Singapore Indonesia">`
`$projrow['title']` to be inserted into `<span class="title">Title</span>`

```
<li class="gallery-item Singapore Indonesia">
    <div class="gallery-contents">
        <div id="id1" class="thumbnail gallery-trigger">
            <span>
                <span class="title">Title</span>
                <img src="images/project.jpg" alt="" />
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

**Result**

```
    projects.title |categories.title
   +---------------+-----------------
    "Testing 1"    |   "Singapore"
    "Testing 2"    |   "Malaysia"
    "Testing 3"    |   "Indonesia"
    "Testing 4"    |   "Singapore"
    "Testing 4"    |   "Malaysia"
    "Testing 5"    |   "Singapore"
    "Testing 5"    |   "Malaysia"
    "Testing 5"    |   "Indonesia"
    "Testing 6"    |   "Indonesia"
    "Testing 7"    |   "Malaysia"
    "Testing 7"    |   "Indonesia"
```

**What I want**

I don't want the repeated project, I want the to combine the same project but with different categories. Tried `GROUP BY` but it doesn't works for me. Hoping that some of you could provide me with some advice. Thanks!

Comment: `mysql_query()` Ouch. `mysql_*` functions have been deprecated, you should really use `mysqli_*` or PDO. https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: Try group_concat

Comment: @kerbholz ya, I know. But this is my old code, I didn't change yet. Will change after that, thanks for reminding me!

Comment: You only need one query joining all three tables. And if you need the categories as separate items, the result you are showing now is exactly what you need (otherwise `group_concat()` would do). You just need to keep track in php when the title changes and only then display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(categories.title) as "categories.title",
       proj_categ.title as "projects.title"
FROM categories
JOIN proj_categ ON categories.id=proj_categ.categ_id
WHERE proj_id=$projid
GROUP BY proj_categ.title;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! I got it. I have edited your answer, because you should put `proj_categ id` instead of title. No `title` in `proj_categ`

Answer (score 1):

Why you dont using just one query

```
$projects = mysql_query("SELECT projects.title as proj_title,categories.title as cat_title  FROM projects JOIN proj_categ ON projects.id=proj_categ.proj_id JOIN categories ON categories.id=proj_categ.categ_id"); 

while($projrow=mysql_fetch_array($projects))
{
    echo $projrow['proj_title']." ";
    echo $projrow['cat_title ']."<br/>";
}
```

Also **mysql_*** is deprecated and removed from PHP 7 **mysqli_* or PDO**.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. Can you show how to add in group_concat()? Sorry, I'm not familiar with mysql.

Answer (score 0):

```
$res = array();

$projects = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM projects"); 

while($projrow=mysql_fetch_array($projects))
{
    $projid = $projrow['id'];

    $res[$projid] = array('title' => $projrow['title'], 'categories' => array());

    $categories= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories JOIN proj_categ ON categories.id=proj_categ.categ_id where proj_id='".$projid."'"); 

    while($caterow=mysql_fetch_array($categories))
    {
        echo $caterow['title']." ";
        echo $projrow['title']."<br/>";

        $res[$projid]['categories'][] = $caterow['title'];
    }
}
```